# Moodle with Amazon Aurora: Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes

Tags: moodle, amazon-aurora

When performing the database creation, Aurora is throwing the following error to Moodle:

```
ERROR 1709 (HY000): Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.
```

It happens on every table that has a `BIGINT(10) id` column, like `mdl_config` or `mdl_course`.

It seems that it's something related to Barracuda format. The InnoDB file variables present in the database are:

```
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_file_format_check = ON
innodb_file_format_max = Antelope
innodb_file_file_per_table = ON
```

I have to say that in the Aurora Parameter Groups there's no way to change the `innodb_file_format_max` configuration.

The Moodle version I'm using is `3.1.6`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the workaround for this problem. We need to change the ROW_FORMAT to "Dynamic" only then it works. To change the ROW_FORMAT open a following file from Moodle directory:
moodle/lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php

Edit line 420 from { $rowformat = "ROW_FORMAT=Compressed"; } to { $rowformat = "ROW_FORMAT=Dynamic"; }

It actually nullifies the if condition which checks if DB supports Compressed ROW_FORMAT if yes, then set the ROW_FORMAT to Compressed. This is the only hack that which made it working for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are migrating an existing onprem moodle to aws aurora mysql database do the following (assuming linux on both sides).

1. ensure you have upgraded your current moodle to the same version you will be putting on aws (do backups first)
2. perform a mysqldump ex:mysqldump --allow-keywords --opt -uAdminUser -p MoodleDBName > moodle_onprem.sql
3. tar up and compress the the sql (makes the transfer coping smaller) ex: tar cvzf moodle_onprem.tgz moodle_onprem.sql
4. copy the tgz file to a 3c2 instance (probably your moodle server) that has access to auroa using your favorite file transfer tool. (I used a simple scp as we have a direct connection) ex:  scp -i /home/ec2-user/id_rsa someuser@onprembox:/var/www/html/moodle-onprem.tgz ./
5. Untar/compress the file. ex: tar xvzf moodle-onprem.tgz
6. Important step.  Change the row format to DYNAMIC ex: sed -i "s/ ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED/ ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC/" moodle-onprem.sql
7. Also modify moodle/lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php see [Moodle with Amazon Aurora: Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45043269/moodle-with-amazon-aurora-index-column-size-too-large-the-maximum-column-size) answer by rowit to edit line from { $rowformat = "ROW_FORMAT=Compressed"; } to { $rowformat = "ROW_FORMAT=Dynamic"; }
8. Restore your moodle db. ex:mysql -h YourAruoraDBEndNode -u YourAdminUser -p YourMoodleDBName < moodle-onprem.sql

Transfer over your moodle and moodle data to your aws moodle server and you should be all set.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this issue installing Moodle 3.11 on Windows/IIS/MySQL/AWS/RDS. Following the "{ $rowformat = "ROW_FORMAT=Compressed"; } to { $rowformat = "ROW_FORMAT=Dynamic"; }" hints from @Rohit and @ErrorCode67 above I opened "moodle/lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php" but unfortunately line 420 was not what I was expecting.

Instead on line 401 I found the following -

```php
// All the tests passed, we can safely use ROW_FORMAT=Compressed in sql statements.
$this->compressedrowformatsupported = true;
```

Changing to the following seemed to do the trick for me -

```php
$this->compressedrowformatsupported = false;
```

Comment: Yes, this worked for me when migrating to Amazon Aurora with MySQL 5.6 ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to create a *MySQL RDS* instance instead of an *Aurora RDS*, proceed with *Moodle* installation and after it finishes, create a backup of the *MySQL RDS* and restore it inside an *Aurora RDS*.

The problem is only appearing on the install phase, after that *Aurora RDS* can be used with the installation schema, previously created.

Answer (score 0):

Moodle supports AWS Aurora MySQL as of v3.10.

To use this type of database specify auroramysql as the database type in the config.php file for Moodle:

```
$CFG->dbtype    = 'auroramysql';
```

You can also refer to the improvement in the Moodle issue tracker here: https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-58931